# sum columns based on substring in data frame

Tags: r

I have a data.frame of 384 columns. I would like to sum columns that have similar colnames based on a substring of a letter A-H followed by two numbers.
I was trying to store a pattern then loop through, but was not able to define the unique substring.

```
patterns <- unique(substr(names(DT)))  
new <- sapply(patterns, function(xx) rowSums(DT[,grep(xx, names(DT)), drop=FALSE]))
```

my colnames looks like this:

```
   > head(colnames(DT))
[1] "01_001_A01_S1_L001_R1_001" "01_001_A01_S1_L005_R1_001" "01_002_A02_S2_L001_R1_001" "01_002_A02_S2_L005_R1_001"
[5] "01_002_A03_S3_L001_R1_001" "01_002_A03_S3_L005_R1_001"
```

sum columns A01 and A01, A02 and A02 etc...

Comment: `lapply(split.default(df1, names(df1)), rowSums)` ?

Comment: I dont think this works. What does split.default do here?

Comment: Without knowing the pattern in column names like where this substring occurs, it is not clear how to extract it ie. it could be `zA01` or `ZA01ddf` etc.  Your code `unique(substr(names(DT)))` with `substr` doesn't have any start or end arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `substr`ing the `names` of the dataset and use that to `split` the dataset and get the `rowSums`

```
lapply(split.default(df1, substr(names(df1), 8, 10)), rowSums, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Assuming that the column names have fixed number of characters

If it is not of fixed number of characters and the position of 'A01' etc changes, then we use `sub`

```
lapply(split.default(df1, sub("^[^A-Z]*([A-Z][0-9]{2}).*", "\\1",  
                           names(df1))), rowSums, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: But the columns does does not start with A01, it is in the middle of the name.

Comment: Updated my Q with real colnames